# Foundation 6: Responsive Toggle no working

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design, navigation, zurb-foundation

I'm quite affine with Foundation 5 and now I'm trying to use Foundation 6 as my standard. But I've go a problem with the Responsive Toggle (Navigation). As you can see [here](http://demo.chiropraktik-mohme.de), the mobile navigation is always visible and got no content.

This is my HTML:

Menu

```
<div class="top-bar" id="main-navigation">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks to be working properly and performs exactly how the F6 docs suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You are not [adding](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html) **foundation's** default `js` and `css` file. First you need to add that properly.

Yet you can try below css

```
.dropdown.menu .has-submenu:hover .submenu {
  display:block;
}
```

I hope it will helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Maddy! That's not correct. The app.css (containing all styles) is placed in the header. In the footer you can find the foundation.js...

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
    <div class="title-bar" data-responsive-toggle="example-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
  <button class="menu-icon" type="button" data-toggle></button>
  <div class="title-bar-title">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="top-bar" id="example-menu">
  <div class="top-bar-left">
    <ul class="dropdown menu" data-dropdown-menu>
      <li class="menu-text">Site Title</li>
      <li class="has-submenu">
        <a href="#">One</a>
        <ul class="submenu menu vertical" data-submenu>
          <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="top-bar-right">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li><input type="search" placeholder="Search"></li>
      <li><button type="button" class="button">Search</button></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```